# Script error: "An error has occured in the script on the page"

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, perspective

I get a error on my JSP page: 
Script error: "An error has occured in the script on the page"
When I try to run the Eclipse in the debug perspective and I am closing down the browser window of the eclipse where my application is running. 
Because of the error the application hangs, and I am unable to test my application.
Is there any solution to this? I have to restart my eclipse again and again.
This would lead to corrupted files.

Answer (score 1):

If you're lucky, the error message is caused by an Exception. In that case, you can add a Java Exception Breakpoint and the application should pause at the point where the script error is detected.